# How to query related models in django models.py

Tags: python, django

I have a user model which looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Email Address',
        blank=True
    )
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Student')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Administrator')
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Teacher')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Staff')
    is_registrar = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Registrar')
```

and in my `StudentPorile` model I have a field called `class_advisor` which is related to User model and I need to get the users with `is_teacher` field is True. Now, how do i filter `class_advisor` field to return Users only with `is_teacher=True`?

here's my `StudentProfile` model:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    lrn = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    landline_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    mothers_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_person_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=12, verbose_name='Phone number of Contact Person')
    # class_advisor = IM STUCK HERE
    year_level = models.OneToOneField(Year_Level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    section = models.OneToOneField(Section, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: `users = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)` should give you all user who are teachers

Comment: hi, do you mean class_advisor = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)? Because, i tried to put this in my models.py, it doesn't work. class_advisor doesn't even show in my django admin page.

Comment: oh I guess you are confusing models and queries, in models we only define a structure and not return anything, so you must add a `class_advisor` field, so in models you must define `class_advisor= models.ManyToManyField(User)` , now while saving send in only users who are teachers to this field, to restrict saving other users there is an option in django, you must override django's save method for the current model

Answer (score 0):

This should return you a `queryset` of all the Users who have their `is_teacher` attribute set to `True`

`User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)`

views.py

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
       filtered_users = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)
       return render(request, 'home.html', context={'users': filtered_users})
```

template.html

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{user}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi, do you mean `class_advisor = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)`? Because, i tried to put this in my models.py, it doesn't work. `class_advisor` doesn't even show in my django admin page.

Comment: You can just assign any variable to the aforementioned query and pass it as context to the template. I have edited my answer to reflect them same.